# Generating 1st of months of 20th century - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, date, nsdate, nsdatecomponents, date-formatting

I'm creating a bunch of code to determinate every 1st of each month from 1/1/1901 to 31/12/2000 using Objective-C. I want to get this output :

```
1/1/1901
1/2/1901
1/3/1901
.
.
.
1/11/2000
1/12/2000
```

But I'm getting the last day of each month :

```
31/1/1901
28/2/1901
.
.
.
30/11/2000
31/12/2000
```

Here is my code :

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

@autoreleasepool {

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    date = [formatter dateFromString:@"01/01/1901"];
    NSDate *stopDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    stopDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"31/12/2000"];

    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    while ([[date earlierDate:stopDate] isEqualToDate:date]){
        NSDateComponents *comps = [cal components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:date];

        if ([comps month] == 12){
            [comps setMonth:1];
            [comps setYear:[comps year]+1];
        }else{
            [comps setMonth:[comps month]+1];
        }

        date = [cal dateFromComponents:comps];
        NSLog(@"%@",date);
    }

}

return 0;
}
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: For starters output the date with a date formatter: `NSLog(@"date: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:date]);`

Comment: How this could solve the problem?

Comment: It was not a solution. OTOH, the code works for me. Perhaps you have a time zone issue that is causing the wrong date, check the hour. A simple NSLog of the date uses your local time zone.

Comment: It also works fine with me too, now. The formatter thing you said just changed everything (I really wonder how). It's not about timezones, I'm not using hours.

Comment: Why are you specifying `NSWeekdayCalendarUnit`? I think you mean to use `NSDayCalendarUnit`.

Comment: No, I'm using `NSWeekdayCalendarUnit` for another purpose on the program. The whole code isn't shown here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create and display the dates with the same timezone. Use

```
NSLog(@"date: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

to print the dates.

```
NSLog(@"date: %@", date);
```

Uses your local timezone including hours. NSDate stores the date in seconds relative to GMT.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateStyle: NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

        NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

        NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        [comps setDay:1];

        for (int year = 1901; year <= 2000; year++) {
            [comps setYear:year];
            for (int month = 1; month <= 12; month++) {
                [comps setMonth:month];

                NSDate *date = [cal dateFromComponents:comps];
                NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:date]);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```